# Game of life python - too many resources

Tags: python, tkinter, conways-game-of-life, tkinter-canvas

i have started programming and tried the 'game of life' and everything is fine on 20x20 boards, but if i take board sizes like 100 or more, after 100 generations the program needs 500mb of RAM and 25% of my CPU (and needs more for every gen), which i guess is bad. so i think, i have a logical error, which takes more RAM every generation. posting the code below

```
import time
from tkinter import *

class cell(object):
    def __init__(self,lives):
        self.lives = lives

    def set(self, alive):
        self.lives=alive


class grid(object):
    gen  = 0
    def __init__(self,height,width,file=None):
        if(file is None):
            self.root=Tk()
            self.root.title("Game of Life")
            self.canvas=Canvas(self.root,height =height*6, width=width*6)
            self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
            self.matrix=[[cell(False) for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
            self.next_grid = [[cell(False) for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
            self.width= width
            self.height=height
        else:
            pass
            #comes later with fileinput

    def print_grid(self):
        for i in range(self.height):
            for j in range(self.width):
                if(self.matrix[i][j].lives):
                    pass
                    self.canvas.create_rectangle(j*6,i*6,j*6+4,i*6 + 4,fill="black")
                elif(not self.matrix[i][j].lives):
                    self.canvas.create_rectangle(j*6,i*6,j*6+5,i*6 + 5,fill="white",width=0)#invalid command name ".9727696"?!

    def set_cell(self, height,width,live):
        self.matrix[height][width].set(live)

    def count_neighbours(self,height,width):
        counter = 0
        for hi in range(height-1,height+2):
             for wi in range(width -1,width+2):
                if(hi < self.height and hi > -1 and wi < self.width and wi > -1):
                   if(self.matrix[hi][wi].lives):
                        counter = counter +1

        if(self.matrix[height][width].lives):
            counter = counter -1
        return counter

    def does_survive(self,i,j):
        neighbours = self.count_neighbours(i,j)
        result =False
        if(self.matrix[i][j].lives):
            if(neighbours == 2 or neighbours == 3):
               result = True
        elif (neighbours == 3):
            result =  True
        return result


    def next_gen(self):

    self.next_grid = [[cell(False) for x in range(self.width)] for y in range(self.height)]
        self.gen = self.gen +1
        for i in range(self.height):
            for j in range(self.width):
                self.next_grid[i][j].set(self.does_survive(i,j))
        self.matrix = self.next_grid


def test():
    cell1=cell(True)
    cell2=cell(False)
    cell2.set(True)
    place=grid(150,150)
    place.set_cell(50,60,True)
    place.set_cell(51,60,True)
    place.set_cell(51,59,True)
    place.set_cell(52,60,True)
    place.set_cell(50,61,True)
    for i in range(1000):
        place.print_grid()
        #time.sleep(0.01)
        place.next_gen()
        place.canvas.update()
    place.root.mainloop()
    test()
```

it's the first time i'm using graphics in general and yeah... i hope you can help me :D

edit: i've found the mistake and am working on a better performance, but now i have the problem, that the generations are weird if i dont clear the next_gen grid in the ... can you help me?

Comment: your print_grid code creates rectangles and they are never removed, you just stack new ones on top of old ones. Consider rather having an array of rectangles (constant) and only changing their colors (or removing old ones each iteration).

Comment: @lejlot: This could be an answer already.

Comment: Thanks, i used self.canvas.delete("all") before printing the new grid and it helps , but now the generations look a bit weird... could you look if my rules in does_survive are right written?

Comment: Actually there's no reason to create rectangles every generation since only the last one will ever be displayed because `place.root.mainloop()` isn't called until all the earlier ones have been overwritten (or deleted). If you want to display of each generation to animate the process, consider using the tkinter widget `.after()` method to have `place.next_gen()` called periodically to update the constant array of rectangle @lejlot suggested. You also need to fix the indentation of your code, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a grid of size 150x150, you are creating 22,500 canvas items. **Every time you call `print_grid` you are creating *another* 22,500 canvas items.** Since you are calling `print_grid` 1000 times, you are creating over 22 *million* canvas items. While the canvas is fairly powerful, it can't handle this many items.

You should create the grid exactly once, and then every time you call `print_grid` you should simply modify the rectangles you've already created. When you create a rectangle it returns an id. You can then pass this id to the canvas `itemconfigure` method to change properties of that items.